# How to transfer large files from PC to Android reliably (via USB) with the option to pause

Tags: windows, android, file-transfer

I want to transfer a large folder of ~3GB from my PC to my Pixel 4. Windows Explorer works ok but it may freeze when transferring large files and the remaining time shown is not reliable.
I am looking for ways or any applications that show reliable remaining transfer time and also allow users to pause during transfer because the process is probably going to take my time and I will need to leave the room with my phone.
Something like Xyplorer may work except it is still using native transfer.
TeraCopy works ok within windows (allows verification but does not show time) but it does not work when I try to copy files to android folder.
I prefer to use USB transfer because I believe it is way faster than using wifi.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here. We are happy to help solve your problem, but asking us to simply tell you the app to use will get your question closed. Please use the EDIT button to make your question on-topic. Read our helpful Help section to further help you.

Comment: there are many apps available which can work over wifi to transfer a  large file from pc to mobile like PushBullet,ShareIt  etc

Comment: @IshanShah I am looking for a solution that works via USB transfer because I assume it would be the fastest solution over any wifi solutions?

Comment: @music2myear I altered my questions. It may looked like product recommendations, but if you look at the title, the problem is clear.

Comment: @wada Unless your phone (and computer) have good USB3 connectors, WiFi has a significant chance of being faster and better suited for reliable and speedy large file transfers. Also, yes your title presents a problem, but the body of your question still asks explicitly for suggestions for apps to solve the problem for you.